# Uses for a gastric bypass

Tags: science-based, biology, society, social-norms, trans-humanism

The world of Pandemonium is a world in another universe where humans may exist, that is gravitationally connected to Earth in our universe.  Over the course of history since the big bang, these universes have periodically collided, transferring organised matter from one to the other, including humans.

On Pandemonium, the science of genetics surpassed that of our society long ago, and genetic transhumanism has become the norm, in order to adapt the humans that live there to their alien environment.

One of the heritable transhuman adaptations that I am considering is a "gastric bypass".  This is effectively a link straight through the body from the oesophagus to the rectum.  The regular intestinal tract and the bypass are kept separate from each-other by sphincters that are under conscious control.  The oesophagus, rectum and bypass are thickened and reinforced relative to the rest of the gastrointestinal tract in order to make it tough and non-absorbtive, for the purpose of allowing the person who possesses it to consume poisoned food or drink without absorbing significant amounts of the poison and without being impolite by refusing to consume the 'edibles'.  Such suspect food would be stored in the gastric bypass prior to its expulsion undigested at a later time.

A secondary use for the gastric bypass is to allow the person possessing the bypass to be impaled through their body by a foreign object from anus to mouth safely and reasonably comfortably, where such impalement of a non-enhanced person would be fatal.  This might be performed for purposes of identification, ritual and/or restraint.

What is the feasability of this gastric bypass system, and are there other factors and scenarios that I should consider that would affect its feasibility?

EDIT: Make it clearer that this is a genetically-engineered heritable trait, not surgery involving an engineered organ.

Comment: This feature would also make binging and purging a la Roman vomitoriums slightly more feasible, and therefore might be favored by filthy-rich-hedonists. All the flavor, none of the fat and heart disease.

Comment: @MediocreFantasy Yes... and no acid-related tooth erosion that you get from frequent purging.

Answer (score 3):

#### Technically Feasible

**Description**: Essentially, what you are looking at is a secondary through-body tract that bypasses the entire gut. This tract must do two things:

1. It must be controllable by the conscious brain, as are other parts of the body like the arms and legs;
2. It must not allow (too much) absorption, e.g. poisons or toxins that might be safely ingested by Pandemonians, but not Terrans

**Assumptions**: I make the assumption that the Pandemonians are not eating things that would destroy human tissues under ordinary circumstances like brief handling.

**Process**: This can be accomplished, even with 21st century terran surgical techniques using autotransplantation techniques.  The bypass itself will be constructed by taking a free flap of full thickness skin and subcutaneous tissues, from the thigh or from the abdomen, made to measure and formed into a tube of suitable length.

Sphincters and bypass ejectors can be formed using muscle flaps to close off either end of the bypass. Both the bypass itself and the sphincters will be ennervated and vascularised using available nerves, blood vessels and appropriate microsurgical techniques.

The bypass bloc will be attached to the native gut using standard anastamotic techniques and devices.

Functionality of the bypass will require a period of adjustment and physio-occupational therapy to teach the participant how to control the sphincters. This period will be occupied by participants learning how to properly use their bypasses in a safe manner: just because you can now stick a sword up your bum, doesn't mean you won't stab your own brain in the process. Essentially, your participants will be learning how to swallow swords and how to properly aim said swords once they are properly engaged at either end.

**Conjecture**: I would hazard the guess that in addition to "genetic sciences", the Pandemonians have also more advanced medical and surgical technologies than Terrans. I would therefore expect that they might be able to grow cartilage rings, which would help keep the bypass patent. Currently, we could use autologous bone and cartilage grafts, but there's only so much of that resource available! I would also expect that nerve regeneration, nerve grafting, and brain-body connections will be much better understood, resulting in in far more positive outcomes.

Comment: Any really harmful substance, like strong acids/bases or smelly toxins would cause an obvious adulteration to food or drink, and it would be reasonable for someone to reject them.  The bypass was originally intended to be used where subtle poison is suspected, but it might give offense to accuse the host... or where a person is being threatened with violence if they don't consume an obvious poison.

Comment: Also, the bypass is a heritable trait, not a surgically implanted device.

Comment: @MontyWild --- You didn't say that in the question. Oh well! Had you indicated that it was inheritable, I would say that no, it is not feasible from the perspective of current Terran technology or science. Theoretically, sure, genetic surgery. From the Pandemonian perspective, of course it could be feasible! Their science is far in advance of the Terran understanding. If they can manipulate genes so easily, then creating a secondary tube bypass is trivially easy and comes without any of the issues I mentioned.

Comment: I thought that I had implied it by mentioning their skill at genetics...  You know what happens when someone makes assumptions, though.

Comment: @MontyWild --- I won't hold it against either of us!